# Why has $\mathcal{L}$ at most a finite number of points, where the tangent fails to exist

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebraic-geometry

Suppose

- $F(x,y)$ is polynomial .
- $\mathcal{L} =\{x+iy:x,y\in \mathbb{R},F(x,y)=0 \}\subseteq L$ .
- We know that ${\ L}$ is algebraic curve.

Why  has $\mathcal{L}$ **at most a finite number** of points, where the tangent fails
to exist?

Comment: I guess $F(x,y)$ has coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$ and could assume it is irreducible. Then the tangent fails to exist means $F=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}F=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}F=0$, there are only finite such points.

Comment: @WZ_Bosons - Thank you , I dont understand why does "there are only finite such points"?

Comment: There is a theorem in algebraic curves, Bezout's theorem, you could google it, which shows there are only finite such points.

Comment: @WZ_Bosons - In this question (by Bezout's theorem), What is second curve that, $G(x,y)=0$?

Comment: $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}F$, or the other one.

Comment: @WZ_Bosons - Can we say that ${\cal L} = \bigcup\limits_{k = 1}^h {{\chi _k}}$ where $χ_k$ is suitable smooth curves?

Comment: No, the irreducible components $\chi_k$ could be singular, like $y^2-x^3=0$, it is singular at the origin.

Comment: @WZ_Bosons - Thank you. Please see this paper,  in Theorem 7 page 11, in second part says that, ${\cal L} = \bigcup\limits_{k = 1}^h {{\chi _k}}$ ?where $χ_k$ is suitable smooth curves.(http://math.ntua.gr/~ppsarr/mcblp.pdf)?

Comment: In theorem 7, it says that it is only piece-wise smooth. I guess what you mean by smooth is that it is a union of smooth pieces $\chi_i$. The example $y^3-x^3=0$ has two smooth pieces, if this is what you mean!

Comment: @WZ_Bosons - Thanks and thanks.

Comment: @WZ_Bosons - Thanks for your answers, but in first comment , I dont understand why does " $F(x,y)$ has coefficients in $R$ and could assume it is irreducible. **Then the tangent fails to exist** "?

Comment: $F(x,y)$ has coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$ means it is in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$, the real polynomial ring, which is a UFD. So the locus $F(x,y)=0$ is the union of $f_i(x,y)=0$ provided $F= \Pi_i f_i$.

Comment: @WZ_Bosons - I have a problem, I shad be grateful if you see this link and help me.       http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1737524/how-can-we-prove-by-b%C3%A9zouts-theorem-that-l-has-finitely-many-singularities